# rotating an image with mouse move event

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I am trying achieve a turntable like style where i finding it difficult to move the disk with mouse move event.

This my xaml code

```
<!-- Disk rotating code -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="disk" Margin="0,-60,0,0">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTransform" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                     From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:5"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"> 
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Rectangle x:Name="ttbg" Margin="5,200,30,0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.503,0.503" Height="420" Width="420" MouseLeftButtonDown="press_down" MouseLeftButtonUp="press_up" MouseMove="press_move" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/ttbg.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="myTransform" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
```

This is my C# code

```
private void press_down(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

    }

    private void press_up(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    }

    private void press_move(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

    }
```

Question from a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky and requires some coding.  But I will give it a try.

First of all I have changed your XAML so that I will be using a [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead of the `StackPanel` that you have used.  In this case I prefer the `Canvas` because it allows me to position the turntable image using absolute coordinates so that I know exactly where the center of the turntable is.  The XAML now looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TurnTable.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    >

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <!-- Disk rotating code -->
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="angleAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="myTransform" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                     From="0" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                     >
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase />
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <Rectangle x:Name="ttbg" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="420" Width="420" MouseLeftButtonDown="press_down" MouseLeftButtonUp="press_up" MouseMove="press_move"  >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/ttbg.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="myTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Also note that I gave the storyboard a duration of 1 second and I gave it an `EasingFunction` to give the animation a nice look and feel.

In the codebehind for the usercontrol I am using [`Math.Atan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan.aspx) function to calculate the angle to turn the turntable upon mouse movement.  I am using the coordinates of the mouse relative to the center of the turntable to determine the value to feed to `Math.Atan`.  The code ends up looking as follows:

```
namespace TurnTable
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        Point _centerOfTurnTable;
        Point _startMousePosition;
        Point _lastMousePosition;
        bool _isMouseCaptured = false;
        double _deltaAngle;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void press_down(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _centerOfTurnTable = new Point
            (
                Canvas.GetLeft(ttbg) + ttbg.ActualWidth / 2d,
                Canvas.GetTop(ttbg) + ttbg.ActualHeight / 2d
            );

            myStoryboard.Pause();

            _startMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
            _isMouseCaptured = true;
            _lastMousePosition = _startMousePosition;
        }

        private void press_up(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isMouseCaptured)
            {
                _isMouseCaptured = false;

                angleAnimation.From = myTransform.Angle;
                angleAnimation.To = myTransform.Angle + _deltaAngle * 100;
                _deltaAngle = 0;
                myStoryboard.Begin();
            }
        }

        private void press_move(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point currentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
            if (_isMouseCaptured && Math.Abs(currentMousePosition.X - _centerOfTurnTable.X) > 5)
            {
                _deltaAngle = GetAngleDelta(currentMousePosition);

                myTransform.Angle += _deltaAngle;
                _lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition;
            }
        }

        private double GetAngleDelta(Point currentMousePosition)
        {
            double lastAngleDegrees = GetAngleDegrees(_lastMousePosition);
            double newAngleDegrees = GetAngleDegrees(currentMousePosition);

            if (Math.Sign(lastAngleDegrees) != Math.Sign(newAngleDegrees))
            {
                lastAngleDegrees = newAngleDegrees;
            }
            double delta = newAngleDegrees - lastAngleDegrees;
            return delta;
        }

        private double GetAngleDegrees(Point position)
        {
            return 180d / Math.PI * Math.Atan((position.Y - _centerOfTurnTable.Y) / (position.X - _centerOfTurnTable.X));
        }
    }
}
```

The code allows you to turn the turntable and when depressing the mouse an animation will be started to allow the turntable to slowly come to a complete stop which gives it a nice touch.

Comment: Thank jakob for the reply well trying your code gives me an error  on angleAnimation.From = myTransform.Angle;
                angleAnimation.To = myTransform.Angle + _deltaAngle * 100;
  angleAnimation does not exists for the current context.

Comment: If you take a look at my XAML you will see that angleAnimation is the name of the DoubleAnimation.  So you have to define angleAnimation in the XAML.